# a strange complex number inequality

Tags: inequality, complex-numbers

> If $z_1,...,z_n\in\mathbb{C}$ satisfy $\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}|1-z_j|<\dfrac{1}{2}$ then $$\left\vert 1-\prod_{j=1}^{n}z_j\right\vert\leq 2\sum_{j=1}^{n}|1-z_j|.$$

I don't know how to start. Can someone give me some hints what should I do?

Comment: Are you sure you want the sum to $n-1$? If so, this gives you no control of $z_n$, and so I'm less inclined to believe that the inequality could be true (but maybe it could be).  $\quad$ Can you prove the $n = 2$ case?

Answer (score 2):

Let $w_j=z_j-1$  and $S_n=\sum^n_{j=1}|w_j|$. Then

I think there might be a typo in the OP's and that the inequality in the hypothesis is $\sum^n_{j=1}|1-z_j|<\frac12$. It that is indeed the case, then setting  let$w_j=z_j-1$  and $S_n=\sum^n_{j=1}|w_j|$ we have that

\begin{align}
\big|1-\prod^n_{j=1}(1+w_j)\big|&\leq\big|1-\prod^n_{j=1}(1+|w_j|)\big|\\
&\leq e^{\sum^n_{j=1}|w_j|}-1=\Big(\sum^n_{j=1}|w_j|\Big)\Big(1+\frac{S_n}{2}+\ldots +\frac{(S_n)^{m-1}}{m!}+\ldots\Big)\\
&\leq \Big(\sum^n_{j=1}|w_j|\Big)\Big(1+\frac12+\frac14+\ldots +\frac{1}{2^{m-1}}+\ldots\Big)=2\sum^n_{j=1}|1-z_j|
\end{align}

Comment: How the first "$\leq$" happens?

Comment: @AlexNguyen: Notice that $$P_n:=\big(\prod^n_{j=1}(1+w_j) \big)-1=\Big(1+\sum^n_{j=1}w_j +\sum_{1\leq i <j\leq n}w_iw_j+\ldots +w_1w_2\cdots w_n\Big)-1$$ Hence
\begin{align}
|P_n|&\leq \sum^n_{j=1}|w_j|+\sum_{1\leq i <\leq n}|w_iw_j|+\ldots+|w_1w_2\cdots w_n|\\
&=\big(\prod^n_{j=1}(1+|w_j|)\big) -1
\end{align}